# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Image'

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a folder with images, I read all the images and resize them from 300x300 to 96x96 with this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

size = (96,96)
list_of_images = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    image_directory = path+ '\\' +str(filename)
    print(image_directory)
    image = Image.open(image_directory)
    image = image.resize(size)
    list_of_images.append(image)
```

The list_of_images is a list of images (e.g [Image,Image,Image]) instead of arrays.

The problem occurs when I am trying to split the list and then put it together:

```
faults = list_of_images[0:700]
normal = list_of_images[1115:1800]

fault_label = Labels[0:700]
normal_label = Labels[1115:1800]
train_images = np.concatenate((faults, normal), axis = 0)
train_labels = np.concatenate((fault_label,normal_label), axis = 0)
```

When I am trying to concatenate I am getting this error:

```
train_images = np.concatenate((faults, normal), axis = 0)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Image'
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thank you.

### edit

adapted from the unreadable comment

```
mgs1 = [] 
for i in range(len(names)): 
    img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO() 
    list_of_images[i].save(img_byte_arr, format='PNG') 
    img_byte_arr = img_byte_arr.getvalue() 
    imgs1.append(img_byte_arr)
```

Comment: getting the image bytecode? concatenate that?

Comment: I tried to using this code but it didnt work imgs1 = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
    list_of_images[i].save(img_byte_arr, format='PNG')
    img_byte_arr = img_byte_arr.getvalue()
    imgs1.append(img_byte_arr)

Comment: Why are you using `concatenate` to join two lists that contain `Image` objects?  `np.concatenate` works on and returns numpy  arrays.

Comment: I think you want to do `train_images = faults + normal`?